# Open Addressing of Double Hashing

Tags: c, hash

**Open Addressing of Double Hashing**

Can't seem to get it right. There are errors in certain hidden cases (both input and output cant be seen), so I am trying to see if anyone can assist in spotting the errors.

I am implementing an open addressing hash table by double hashing to perform insertion and deletion. The structure of hash slots is given below, and a hash table with 37 hashslots is created in the main function.

The hash functions are provided. The `hash2()` is the incremental hash function for double hashing.

Both functions' return value is the number of key comparisons done during insertion and deletion respectively. Inserting a duplicate key will return -1. If the number of key comparisons is more than the table size, it implies that the table is full. For the deletion function, it will return -1 if the deleting key does not exist. The number of key comparisons in deletion cannot be more than table size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TABLESIZE 37
#define PRIME     13

enum Marker {EMPTY,USED,DELETED};

typedef struct _slot{
    int key;
    enum Marker indicator;
} HashSlot;

int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);
int HashDelete(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);


int hash1(int key);
int hash2(int key);

int main()
{
    int opt;
    int i;
    int key;
    int comparison;
    HashSlot hashTable[TABLESIZE];

    for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++){
        hashTable[i].indicator = EMPTY;
        hashTable[i].key = 0;
    }

    printf("============= Hash Table ============\n");
    printf("|1. Insert a key to the hash table  |\n");
    printf("|2. Delete a key from the hash table|\n");
    printf("|3. Print the hash table            |\n");
    printf("|4. Quit                            |\n");
    printf("=====================================\n");
    printf("Enter selection: ");
    scanf("%d",&opt);
    while(opt>=1 && opt <=3){
        switch(opt){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a key to be inserted:\n");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            comparison = HashInsert(key,hashTable);
            if(comparison <0)
                printf("Duplicate key\n");
            else if(comparison < TABLESIZE)
                printf("Insert: %d Key Comparisons: %d\n",key, comparison);
            else
                printf("Key Comparisons: %d. Table is full.\n",comparison);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a key to be deleted:\n");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            comparison = HashDelete(key,hashTable);
            if(comparison <0)
                printf("%d does not exist.\n", key);
            else if(comparison <= TABLESIZE)
                printf("Delete: %d Key Comparisons: %d\n",key, comparison);
            else
                printf("Error\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++) printf("%d: %d %c\n",i, hashTable[i].key,hashTable[i].indicator==DELETED?'*':' ');
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter selection: ");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
    }
    return 0;
}

int hash1(int key)
{
    return (key % TABLESIZE);
}

int hash2(int key)
{
    return (key % PRIME) + 1;
}

int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int hash = hash1(key);
    int i = 0;
    int comparisons = 0;

    while (hashTable[hash].indicator == USED && hashTable[hash].key != key && i < TABLESIZE) {
        hash = (hash + hash2(key)) % TABLESIZE;
        i++;
        comparisons++;
    }

    if (hashTable[hash].key == key&&hashTable[hash].indicator == USED) {
        return -1;  // Key already exists
    }

    if (i >= TABLESIZE) {
        return comparisons ;  // Table is full, count initial comparison
    }

    hashTable[hash].key = key;
    hashTable[hash].indicator = USED;
    return comparisons ;  // Count initial comparison
}

int HashDelete(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int hash = hash1(key);
    int i = 0;
    int comparisons = 1;

    while (hashTable[hash].indicator != EMPTY && i < TABLESIZE) {
        if (hashTable[hash].indicator == USED && hashTable[hash].key == key) {
            hashTable[hash].indicator = DELETED;
            return comparisons;
        }
        hash = (hash + hash2(key)) % TABLESIZE;
        i++;
        comparisons++;
    }

    return -1;  // Key not found
}
```

Comment: don't have any input values that cause an error when I debug, hidden cases that are completely unknown inputs . I am only asked to write for the  HashInsert and HashDelete functions only so it is based on string matching . I think conceptually there is a mistake as I am not very familiar with open addressing double hashing

Comment: If only `HashInsert()` and `HashDelete()` are your code, and especially if that means we are to assume that everything else is correct, then that really ought to be specified in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tombstones were not accounted for when inserting keys

Slots marked deleted (i.e. tombstones) implies that that the "chain" has not terminated and the search for a key must continue until reaching either an `EMPTY` slot or having exhausted all slots.

This was done correctly in your example when deleting a key: the search for a key only stops when reaching an `EMPTY` slot and not a `DELETED` slot.

This was however not done when inserting a key. In this case, insertion can be broken down into 2 parts

1. Finding the insertion point by probing
   This is done by finding the first slot in the probing chain that isn't in use (which you did correctly)
2. Searching the hashtable for duplicates
   This is done by continuing the search of the key as described earlier (which you missed)

> Note that once all slots have been used at least once, every insertion will take the maximum number of key comparisons (all keys will have to be searched)
> To prevent this, rehashing/re-positioning of slots is required to restore `DELETED` slots to `EMPTY` which seems to be beyond the scope of your exercise.

Below is the corrected code, where we first find the insertion point and save it separately before continuing our search for duplicates.

```c
int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int hash = hash1(key);
    int insertAt, i = 0;
    int comparisons = 0;

    while (hashTable[hash].indicator == USED && hashTable[hash].key != key && i < TABLESIZE) {
        hash = (hash + hash2(key)) % TABLESIZE;
        i++;
        comparisons++;
    }
    if (i >= TABLESIZE) {
        return comparisons ;  // Table is full, count initial comparison
    }

    insertAt = hash;   // Save the insertion point first
    // We will continue probing till the end (i.e. hitting an EMPTY slot)
    // to check if the key is indeed not in the hashTable

    while (hashTable[hash].indicator != EMPTY && i < TABLESIZE) {
        if (hashTable[hash].indicator == USED) {    // Do a key compare if slot is in use
            comparisons++;
            if (hashTable[hash].key == key) // Key already exists
                return -1;
        }
        hash = (hash + hash2(key)) % TABLESIZE;
        i++;
    }

    hashTable[insertAt].key = key;
    hashTable[insertAt].indicator = USED;
    return comparisons ;  // Count initial comparison
}
```

### Miscounting of `comparisons` when deleting keys

This a minor mistake, but you are miscounting the number of comparisons when deleting a key.
Key comparisons should not made on tombstones, below is the corrected code.

```c
int HashDelete(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int hash = hash1(key);
    int i = 0;
    int comparisons = 0;    // Number of comparisons should start from 0

    while (hashTable[hash].indicator != EMPTY && i < TABLESIZE) {
        if (hashTable[hash].indicator == USED) {
            comparisons++;      // Only compare when the slot is USED
            if (hashTable[hash].key == key) {
                hashTable[hash].indicator = DELETED;
                return comparisons;
            }
        }
        hash = (hash + hash2(key)) % TABLESIZE;
        i++;
    }

    return -1;  // Key not found
}
```